# Best DB backend taking account CAP Theorem and the data paradigm

Tags: sql, nosql, distributed-computing

Leaving performance point view I would focus my question arround the CAP Theorem and how it should be important when you are looking for the best solution.

My data pradigm is easy, is just a set of *id, timestamp, value* tuples. This value is only write at first time and after it, it is just read.

should I try a *Partion* and *Availability* kind of backends ? like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)

Comment: This is not a straight answer, but with so many of these NoSQL databases being available for free, why not just start downloading them and trying them? You can usually get a single node running in minutes and I think that will help you narrow down your options.

Comment: This is not a answer, I'm asking about the probably relationship between data model and how it should be take care on different NoSql CAP Theorem approximations, leaving consistence like Cassandra  or availability like MongoDb.

Comment: I told you it wasn't an answer, that's why it's a comment. =) You asked if you should try A and P and I agreed. You should give it a try. =)